# How to use ParamGridBuilder for ASL 0.9.0 on pyspark 3.2.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using ASL 0.9.0 on pyspark 3.2.0. When I set up the model, it only allowed me to set up as a blank model

```
asl = ALS()
```

If I input any param I would get error:

```
als = ALS(rank=5)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7f1df7a9fa59> in <module>
----> 1 als = ALS(rank=5)

TypeError: ALS() takes no arguments
```

When I trained the model with fixed parameter it worked fine.

```
model = als.train(train_rdd, rank=5, iterations=5, lambda_=0.01, blocks=- 1, nonnegative=False, seed=None)
```

However, when I tried to use ParamGridBuilder, I kept getting message 'ALS' object has no attribute for all the parameters.

My code:

```
param_grid = ParamGridBuilder() \
            .addGrid(als.rank, [10, 50, 100, 150]) \
            .addGrid(als.iterations, [20]) \
            .addGrid(als.regParam, [.01, .05, .1, .15]) \
            .build()
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-0e6e7cbffc91> in <module>
----> 1 param_grid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(als.rank, [10, 50, 100, 150]).addGrid(als.iterations, [20]).addGrid(als.regParam, [.01, .05, .1, .15]).build()

AttributeError: 'ALS' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

Comment: https://softwaremill.com/spark-ml-hyperparameter-tuning/ This is eaxactly what you looking for